# Aligning rows of tables by matching first elements

Tags: excel, vba

Seeking direction from proper VBA programmers of how I could best approach writing some tricky code efficiently. I seek to align two tables A and B of dimensions [*n* X 4] and [*m* X 5] respectively.

The conditions are:

1. a match between the tables first element of every nth and mth row determines alignment.
2. A (left) and B (right) are neighbours but B is fixed. So, only rows in A can reorder to align properly with matched rows of the mth element in B.
3. Attached is a representation of the procedure -

List item

[image]

Various Q&A sites (including Stackoverflow) do not address the specific conditions imposed by my problem.

Example  of code so far:

```
    Dim t1s As Long: t1s = 1 ' start column of table 1
    Dim t2s As Long: t2s = 6 ' start column of table 2
    Dim t1l As Long: t1l = 5 - 1 ' length of columns of table 1 (-1)
    Dim t2l As Long: t2l = 6 - 1 ' length of columns on table 2 (-1)

    Dim startRow As Long: startRow = 2

    Dim r As Long ' current row var
    Dim rMatch As Long ' to hold matching row on table 2

    With Rec_9 ' change to whatever worksheet you're using
        For r = startRow To .Cells(.Rows.Count, t1s).End(xlUp).Row ' cycle through to last row
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(t2s), .Cells(r, t1s).Value) > 0 Then
    
                rMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(r, t1s).Value, .Columns(t2s), 0)
            
                .Range(Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Range(Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Value2 = "*"
            
                .Range(Cells(rMatch, t1s), Cells(rMatch, t1s + t1l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
                .Range(Cells(rMatch, t1s), Cells(rMatch, t1s + t1l)).Value2 = .Range(Cells(r + 1, t1s), Cells(r + 1, t1s + t1l)).Value2
            
                .Range(Cells(r + 1, t1s), Cells(r + 1, t1s + t1l)).Value2 = "*"
            
                r = r + 1 ' make sure to skip the next row since one has been inserted to avoid infinite looping
            
            End If
        Next r
    End With
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The "representation of the procedure" does not says too much... At least, for me. Do you have a piece of code made by your own? We will maybe better understand from it what is to be accomplished. At least a picture with initial situation (with relevant fields) and the final one, after 'procedure' processing, maybe will let us understand what is it about...

Comment: Hi @braX. Pls see code added to Q.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru. Pls see code as best I understand how to translate to VBA. In the image, top matrices are the tables before and bottom 2 after the procedure. Is there a more familiar way I could represent it to you perhaps?

Comment: So As21 value = Bs11 value, which means align those rows, and wherever rows misalign on either table, inject a row of `***` (even on fixed table `B`) ? And you must do this for EVERY match, yes?

Comment: Your example "data" is more confusing than helpful - it would be more useful to show actual (or dummy) values in your "before" and "after"

Comment: I don't think it's really confusing but it's certainly not done in "Excel" mode!

Comment: @jamheadart - yes. Yeah, pushing the boundaries but I have little choice in the matter.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I will populate the matrices to clarify shortly.

Comment: Please check out my answer below, you'll need to adapt it I'm sure but it should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, please note the variable names are not very self explanatory but I like to keep VBA code succinct because the IDE isn't brilliant.

I did this on two tables with only 2 columns (hence t1l = 2 and start col is 4 for tbl2)

```
Sub Align()

Dim t1s As Long: t1s = 1 ' start column of table 1
Dim t2s As Long: t2s = 4 ' start column of table 2
Dim t1l As Long: t1l = 2 - 1 ' length of columns of table 1 (-1)
Dim t2l As Long: t2l = 2 - 1 ' length of columns on table 2 (-1)

Dim startRow As Long: startRow = 2

Dim r As Long ' current row var
Dim rMatch As Long ' to hold matching row on table 2

With Sheet1 ' change to whatever worksheet you're using
    For r = startRow To .Cells(.Rows.Count, t1s).End(xlUp).Row ' cycle through to last row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(t2s), .Cells(r, t1s).Value) > 0 Then
    
            rMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(r, t1s).Value, .Columns(t2s), 0)
            
            .Range(Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
            .Range(Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s), Cells(rMatch + 1, t2s + t2l)).Value2 = "*"
            
            .Range(Cells(rMatch, t1s), Cells(rMatch, t1s + t1l)).Insert shift:=xlDown
            .Range(Cells(rMatch, t1s), Cells(rMatch, t1s + t1l)).Value2 = .Range(Cells(r + 1, t1s), Cells(r + 1, t1s + t1l)).Value2
            
            .Range(Cells(r + 1, t1s), Cells(r + 1, t1s + t1l)).Value2 = "*"
            
            r = r + 1 ' make sure to skip the next row since one has been inserted to avoid infinite looping
            
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

If these two tables had been on different worksheets, we wouldn't need the column lengths of the tables, inserting rows with values would be more simple.

Comment: Thank you, @jamheadart! I follow the logic of this code. There's a '438: Object doesn't support this property or method' error but I have accepted the answer in appreciation.

Comment: On what line do you get the `438` error? I thought the code would need tweaking for your purposes but it shouldn't be throwing an Property/Method error

Comment: For r = startRow To .Cells(.Rows.Count, t1s).End(xlUp).Row ' cycle through to last row. I modified the code slightly but not from this line down.

Comment: Are you MacOS maybe? I wonder if it's the `xlUp` enum that's causing error. That line is a very standard method for getting the last row of a particular column and even if you substitute `t1s` with a column letter instead of a number it, should work fine within the `With SheetWhatever` block.

Comment: Windows. Unsure, VBA is a new language to me and am currently trying different integer variables - substitution failed also - that may allow the counting method deployed … an Excel idiosyncrasy?

Comment: Could try editing your question with the new version of your code and I can see if there's anything further up the code that's causing the issue

Comment: Posted the entire sub, @jamheadart. (note: I assumed t1l and t2l specified number of columns). Let me know if you prefer to move to chat.

Comment: Try replacing `With Rec_9` with `With wsR` --- the `With Sheet1` statement I posted is actually referring to the CodeName (behind the scenes name) of "Sheet1" - it's misleading because the sheet has both name and codename "Sheet1" --- however when you add a worksheet with the name "Rec_9" it will get a simple CodeName like "SheetX" so just trying to use `With Rec_9` wouldn't work. You could refer to it using `With Worksheets("Rec-9")` or, because you've already set a variable (`wsR`) to refer to Worksheet("Rec_9"), just use `With wsR`. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Perfect. @jamheadart, I am in your debt - learnt a lot!